Procore Client authentication failed due to unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method
I am trying to create a login page that has a link to the procore developer portal and they can log in using their procore account. However, when I click on the login with procore button on my login page, it gives me the error above in the question title. I have double checked that my client id and client secret and redirect url are all matching.
This is my security.config:
package com.Lumber.LumberIntegration.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/index.html", "/login").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                        .loginPage("/index.html")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home.html", true)
                        .failureUrl("/index.html?error")
                )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(procoreClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration procoreClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("procore")
                .clientId("o9ABPysGyDZxQg1sI254lsZKY9c4dx5TwMmE3E7yV9A")
                .clientSecret("myClientSecret")
                .scope("openid", "profile", "email")
                .authorizationUri("https://login.procore.com/oauth/authorize")
                .tokenUri("https://login.procore.com/oauth/token")
                .userInfoUri("https://app.procore.com/vapid/me")
                .userNameAttributeName("email")
                .clientName("Procore")
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:3000/login/oauth2/code/procore")
                .authorizationGrantType(org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .build();
    }
}

I am using the sandbox credentials right now but I have no clue what could be causing the error because my client id and client secret and redirect url are all correct in both the security.config file and my application.properties file.
I am using these dependencies to facilitate the connection:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://www.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>lumber-integration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>

but specifically the oauth2 dependencies.
Any help is much appreciated thank you so much!

did you solve it?

I got it working by using the sandbox login domain (login-sandbox.procore.com).
It wasn't immediately obvious from their docs that this is the domain  you're meant to use for sandbox until I found this page (https://procore.github.io/documentation/oauth-endpoints)
I believe redirect_uri must match the one used shown in the portal also.
https://login-sandbox.procore.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=WHATEVER&redirect_uri=http://localhost
